# What is the appropriate ANOVA test for this situation?

Tags: statistics, intuition

So in this experiment I have have 7 devices. The response of each device (call it Y) are each measured ~20 at a 4 different levels of an independent variable (we'll call X). The Y response is known depend on X, and this is clearly the case in the data.

What I am interested in finding out is if any of the devices have statistically different responses compared to the others for a given X. What is the appropriate ANOVA to run here? Should I run a different ANOVA at each level? I've heard of something called a block-design ANOVA; is that appropriate here, and if so could you explain it briefly or give me some good resources?

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Is each of the seven devices of interest in its own right, or are they seven random sampled items representing some population of devices. For each combination of a device and a level of X, do you have one measurement of Y, or several?

Comment: They are each of interest in their own right. I have ~20 measurements of Y for each combination of X/device (though they aren't all exactly the same number of measurements). I'll edit the post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the additional information in your Comment, here is the
model for your experiment.

$$Y_{ijk} = \mu + \alpha_i + \beta_j + \gamma_{ij} + e_{ijk},$$

where $i = 1, \dots, 7$ devices, $j = 1, \dots, 4$ levels of
'X', and $k = 1, \dots, 20$ replications for each device-by-x
combination, and $e_{ijk} \sim N(0, \sigma^2).$

This is a two-factor ANOVA with multiple replications per 'cell'.
The ANOVA table will have rows for 'Device effect', 'x effect',
'Interaction' and 'Error' (or 'Residual'). There will be
$F$-statistics for tests of significance of Device, x-factor,
and interaction.

You will probably want to use software to make the ANOVA table.
If there were $exactly$ 70 replications in each cell, this
would be a 'balanced design'. If not, then you will need to use
a 'general linear model' or 'GLM' procedure to get an
approximate analysis, which should be fine as long as 'about 20'
means something like 'between 15 and 25'.

You say you are particularly interested whether any one device
performs significantly differently from the others for a particular level of factor x. If so, you should have a significant
interaction effect. Then you can look at cell averages
to get an idea which device(s) and which x-level(s) show
interesting patterns and test a few 'ad hoc contrasts' to see if
particular patterns are statistically significant.

If the 'interaction' effect is significant, that might interfere
with the interpretation of 'main effects' for device and x-factor.
For example, you might not be able to say a particular device
has consistently higher or lower T-values than the others. 
Or that a particular level of the x-factor is best or worst.

You will have about $7 \times 4 \times 20 = 560$ observations,
and hence as many 'residuals' from the model. You should look
at a normal probability plot of the residuals to see if they
are roughly normal. Also, if there are occasional far outliers
among the residuals, you should consider whether the corresponding
Y-measurements might have been faulty.

Balanced two-factor ANOVAs should be discussed in early chapters
of any statistics text that covers experimental design. GLM for
unbalanced designs may be discussed separately in a later chapter.

*Note:* Your question mentioned 'block' designs. Terminology about
various kinds of block designs is not exactly standard from on
text to another. Usually, block designs have only one observation
per cell (or perhaps even strategically placed cells with
no observations). In the simplest block designs there is no
possibility of testing for interaction.

Comment: Thanks so much, this clears things up a lot! I hadn't read up too much on two-way ANOVAs, but does indeed look like what I needed.

One quick additional question: could I have done a different ANOVA for each x-level, or is there some kind of problem with doing this? Is the problem just that you would have to adjust $\alpha$ to account for multiple tests, and therefore decrease the test power?

Comment: You could do four separate one-factor (one-way) ANOVAs, one for each level of X. Two disadvantages: (1) Ability to detect differences not as great because 2-factor ANOVA has more info on variability, $e$-term in model. (2) No direct way to look at interaction, which seems one of your key issues. Is 'profile' of performance Y of 7 devices different depending on the level of X. (A $good$ reason to 'pull it apart' into 4 pieces would be if you thought size of variance very different from one level of X to another.)

Comment: Yeah that's exactly why I asked, because the spreads are noticeably different between x-levels, haven't done much to see if it's significant or not yet. I also don't think the interaction is too important to what I'm looking at; the devices should all be the same, so I can likely draw useful conclusions if any of them are different at any level. What exactly do you mean by more info on variability with regards to the e-term int he model?

Comment: Technically speaking, in a 2-way ANOVA DF(Error) is larger and MS(Error) in the denominator of the F-statistic for testing significance of each factor. More df, more power. // No idea what you mean by 'noticeably' different. // Dangerous to give specific advice without knowing subject matter and seeing data. (Call up a doctor and say "I have this funny purplish rash, do you think it's dangerous?" Maybe, maybe not. He/she will want to see it.) OK to steer you to the name of the design you describe, but you probably need local statistical advice from there on.

Comment: Ah I understand the issue with multiple one-way ANOVAs. I have more questions, but I think perhaps they deserve their own full question thread :) Thanks for your help!